# UI Element (Font, button, images) size issue on Mobile first platform Hybrid app on android devices

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

I am supporting a hybrid app built using IBM mobile first platform v7.1 and jQueryMobile framework in which we are facing UI element size issues on android platform. The font, button and all the other elements appearing too large on android app since last 2 weeks. However, the app was working fine few days back.This app is on google playstore and this issue persist over there as well

I don't know what has broken the app since nothing has been changed from the code perspective and its happening only on android OS version 6.0 and above. This might be an android OS version issue

Any Guidance or suggestions will be appreciated  to identify the root cause or fixing the issue

Comment: which JQM version?

Comment: JQM version 1.4.5

Comment: Did you take an Android Webview update on the device? After which you started noticing the issue?

Comment: Or is it after Android O update?

Comment: Also mention if you upgraded to a later MobileFirst iFix

Comment: I have figured out the issue. Its happening because of recent chrome browser update since android  is using web view(system component powered by Chrome) to render html pages. Chrome might have changed something on their recent version(60.x). I have checked my app after downgrading the chrome version on the device and it worked perfectly fine..